# Web Speech API Bug?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) in their documentations, they said:

The `onspeechstart` property of the **SpeechRecognition** interface Fired when sound **that is recognised** by the speech recognition service **as speech** has been detected.

With that in mind why even when I **cough or make some noises** ( that definitely has not any meaning or speech on it ) `SpeechRecognition.onspeechstart` fires?

How can I track if the sound that is received is a **speech** or a **noise**?

Comment: guess that's why the very first sentence about the chrome only API is *This is an experimental technology* ... that's google for you, right

Comment: It's not what we expect from Google!

Comment: At least they should edit their so-called documentations...

Comment: That's Mozilla documentation :)

Comment: speechstart event
Fired when the speech that will be used for speech recognition has started.

Comment: Ok Chrome's Doc here

Comment: Mozilla or Chrome that's the web speech api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Bug of Web Speech API, Hope that Google fix it in future >>>